# Any way to run web scripts from html, that browser runs automaticaly on page download?

Tags: python, parsing, web, python-requests

I'm practicing in parsing web pages with python. So what I do is

```
ans = requests.get(link)
```

Then I use re to extract some information from html, that is stored in

```
ans.content
```

What I faced is that some sites use scripts, that are automatically executed in a browser, but not when I try to download a page using requests. For example, instead of getting a page with information I get something like

```
scripts_to_get_info.run()
```

in html code

Browser is installed on my computer, so as a program that I wrote, this means that, theoretically, I should have a way to run this script and to get information while running python code to parse then.
Is it possible? Any suggestion?

(idea, that this is doable, came from the fact, that when I tried to inspect page in google, I saw real html file without any trashy scripts)

Comment: You're looking for a headless browser.

Comment: I'm looking for 'ans.run_all_scripts()' command

Comment: The response object has no concept of the browser DOM, cookies, local storage, window.location, etc., all of which may be used by the javascript. You're looking for a [headless browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).

Comment: Oh, got it, gonna try tomorrow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe https://phantomjs.org/